# how to filter data from backend in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter, angular-material

I have input where I user can search/type a data and I'm wondering how I can make the user ONLY able to search what was already provided from the backend and forbid them from creating new data.

so in my backend I've "Chart" and "Map" words and I figuring out a way to make the user able to search only this. If I user type other than this and press enter, nothing will happen.

Right now, if the user type other text than this two and press enter, it create a new data and push it to the backend.

I don't want to hard code like this (input == "Chart" || input == "Map") since we will be adding more data in the backend later.

super <= data type like "Chart and Map"

```
<div>
<input matInput #input [formControl]="tagCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
[matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event,null)">
</div>
```

```
  add(event: MatChipInputEvent, event1: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    if (event1 == null) {
      const input = event.input;
      const value = event.value;

      this.tagService.addTag(this._workspace.guid, 'workspace', value).subscribe((tag) => console.log("added", tag));
      // Add Tag
      if ((value || '').trim()) {
        this.superTags.push({ tag: value.trim(), type: TagType.super });
      }
      // Reset the input value
      if (input) {
        input.value = '';
      }
      this.tagCtrl.setValue(null);
    }
    else {
      const input = event1.option;
      const value = event1.option.value;
      this.tagService.addTag(this._workspace.guid, 'workspace', value).subscribe((tag) => console.log("added", tag));
      if (input) {
        input.value = '';
      }
      this.tagCtrl.setValue(null);
    }

  }
```

any recommendation or help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Just add a condition inside add function that check if input value existing on suggestions pickup and don't create new one. and at on options selection prevent duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `suggestions` array that populated by user search.

**Listen on `autocomplete optionActivated` event, when `true`  `onSelected` event will fired with `Enter`, bypass add event.**

```
 add(event: MatChipInputEvent, event1: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
  const input = event.input;
  const value = event.value?.trim();
    if (!value || this._optionActivated) {
        return;
    }   


    // Check if value from create event (Enter, Comma) already exists on search result.
    const suggested = this.suggestions.find(item => item?.id && item.title === value);
    if (suggested) {
     console.log("Already exists on search result", suggested)
     // add to selection list.
    } else {
  this.tagService.addTag(this._workspace.guid, 'workspace', value).subscribe((tag) => {
  console.log("added", tag)
  // add to selection list.
  if (input) {
    input.value = '';
  }
  this.tagCtrl.setValue(null);
}

optionActivated(event: MatAutocompleteActivatedEvent) {
    this._optionActivated = !!event.option;
}

optionClosed() {
    this._optionActivated = false;
}
```

**Template.html:**

```
<mat-autocomplete
    #auto="matAutocomplete"
    (closed)="optionClosed()"
    (optionActivated)="optionActivated($event)"
    (optionSelected)="onSelected($event)"
>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of suggestions" [value]="tag">
        {{ tag.title }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Hi thank you helping but I'm not really sure how that prevent user from creating a new data instead of only able to search what was provided in the backend. Also I did try like that but some reason the "word" are not showing anymore when I type or select from drop down list.

Comment: The issue here is when user focus on autocomplete option and press enter. Two event fired, select option event & add event. and you need to prevent add event and only accept select from autocomplete option.

Comment: If options opened but not focused and user press Enter only add event called you check if item exists in options list only pick and add (Don't create), if not exists then create it.